# Subset multiple dataframes by a range of dates, combining into single dataframe

Tags: r, excel, subset

I have 24 dataframes (named `b1` - `b24`) in a list that follow the general format

```
b1 <- structure(list(Timestamp = c("13/7/1995", "14/7/1995", "15/7/1995", 
                                  "16/7/1995", "17/7/1995", "18/7/1995", "19/7/1995", "20/7/1995", 
                                  "21/7/1995", "22/7/1995", "23/7/1995", "24/7/1995", "25/7/1995", 
                                  "26/7/1995", "27/7/1995", "28/7/1995", "29/7/1995", "30/7/1995", 
                                  "31/7/1995", "1/8/1995"), Rainfall = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
                    CodeofStandard = c(83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L)), 
               row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
b1
#>    Timestamp Rainfall CodeofStandard
#> 1  13/7/1995        0             83
#> 2  14/7/1995        0             83
#> 3  15/7/1995        0             83
#> 4  16/7/1995        0             83
#> 5  17/7/1995        0             83
#> 6  18/7/1995        0             83
#> 7  19/7/1995        0             83
#> 8  20/7/1995        0             83
#> 9  21/7/1995        0             83
#> 10 22/7/1995        0             83
#> 11 23/7/1995        0             83
#> 12 24/7/1995        0             83
#> 13 25/7/1995        0             83
#> 14 26/7/1995        0             83
#> 15 27/7/1995        0             83
#> 16 28/7/1995        0             83
#> 17 29/7/1995        0             83
#> 18 30/7/1995        0             83
#> 19 31/7/1995        0             83
#> 20  1/8/1995        0             83
```

I have sorted each individual dataframe for the top 30 `Rainfall` Events. I want to take the `timestamp` and subset the other 24 for the corresponding `Rainfall` value for that `Timestamp`. There may be missing dates from the other 24 dataframes, so if there's a missing value, I would like `NA` to be extracted in place of the `Rainfall` value.

I have currently been doing this in Excel.. Please see attached to have an idea of my pain

[image]

So for the column b1/136001B (Column G), I have copy and pasted the dates for the top 30 `rainfall` events for that data frame, and that retrieves the corresponding rainfall value for that data frame, in addition to the other data frames along the columns (I:AB). On the left side of the image (B:C:D), contains all the rows from the data frames b1 to b24, which is where the matrix is indexing and matching from.
For example, the values from b1 (column H) (136001B) would consider all the values in column D and would index the corresponding value from C if the date matches. Please see the image below for the equation. Dragging this along the length of b1:b24 and down the length of the top 30 days would give the matrix from above.

[[image]

As you can see there are some NA values, which means that the row containing that particular date does not exist.

Then I would like to covert that matrix into a dataframe with three columns

Where `Station` is the station (b1:b24) for which the rainfall value was retrieved from. `Rainfall` is that said rainfall value and `Origin` is the top 30 rainfall events for the original dataframe in this instance, `b1`

Please see below for the output that I would like to end up with

```
all_b1 <- structure(list(Station = c("b1", "b1", "b1", "b1", "b1", "b1", 
                                 "b1", "b1", "b1", "b1", "b1", "b2", "b2", "b2", "b2", "b2", "b2", 
                                 "b2", "b2", "b2", "b2"), Rainfall = c(66L, 64L, 64L, 62L, 62L, 
                                                                       61L, 61L, 60L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 211L, 176L, 68L, 134L, 135L, 220L, 
                                                                       100L, 57L, 27L, 98L), Origin = c(66L, 64L, 64L, 62L, 62L, 61L, 
                                                                                                        61L, 60L, 59L, 59L, 59L, 210L, 162L, 146L, 143L, 141L, 125L, 
                                                                                                        102L, 101L, 95L, 92L)), row.names = 20:40, class = "data.frame")
all_b1
#>    Station Rainfall Origin
#> 20      b1       66     66
#> 21      b1       64     64
#> 22      b1       64     64
#> 23      b1       62     62
#> 24      b1       62     62
#> 25      b1       61     61
#> 26      b1       61     61
#> 27      b1       60     60
#> 28      b1       59     59
#> 29      b1       59     59
#> 30      b1       59     59
#> 31      b2      211    210
#> 32      b2      176    162
#> 33      b2       68    146
#> 34      b2      134    143
#> 35      b2      135    141
#> 36      b2      220    125
#> 37      b2      100    102
#> 38      b2       57    101
#> 39      b2       27     95
#> 40      b2       98     92
```

Please give me an idea of where to start. I would love to basically start again in R because I have to do this multiple time with other sets of dataframes.

Also please don't be afraid to ask for clarification, I know my rambling mess needs it. Also, my title isn't as clear as it could be, please suggest alternative if you can?

Comment: Please provide an example of the list of data frames you reference. I would take a look at ```purrr::map``` and ```purrr::map_dfr```.

Comment: b1 (the data frame at the top) is the reference data frame, and the other data frames (b1 to b24) follow the same format as that one. Thanks I'll play around with those functions

Comment: I cannot understand the logic of `origin`?

Comment: `Origin` is the top 30 rainfall values for a `b` data frame. For my current data frame, it repeats for the length of dataframe. The purpose of this is to perform correlation analysis. So say we are analysing the `b10` dataframe, we take the dates for the top 30 values for b10, and index the corresponding rainfall values for the other dataframes (`b1-b24`), obviously the rainfall for `b10` will be the same.

Comment: for more clarity, the dataframe could be instead be `Station` , `Rainfall` , `Origin Station` , `Origin` , where for dataframe b10, `Origin Station` would be b10 for the length of the dataframe. `Origin` would be the `rainfall` values for the `b10`. On the other hand, `Station would be `b1` to `b24` with 30 duplicates for each

Comment: So still what does row 31 in above example indicate, it has a value of 210 in origin whereas 211 in rainfall for station b2

Comment: Can I provide excel file link? Perhaps looking at it as a whole would be more clear

Comment: https://surbanajurong-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/colin_fang_smec_com/Ed1J3mUm-zNKtrwgaXJHGm8BkvlyU4HjF5lVp3XIHPfnJg?e=h2Jhby

Comment: It is still not clear! I repeat what does row 31 in above example indicate, it has a value of 210 in origin whereas 211 in rainfall for station b2 ?

Comment: 210 is the value for the specific date for b1, 211 is the value for the corresponding date for b2. Because this is looking at the top 30 values for b1, the `Origin` row values would be the same 30 values for the entire length of the data frame. 
b1 and b2 are separate data frames. Sorry if I am not being clear

Comment: Please give all top 30values of b1 to make it more clear perhaps